# What is light but still dark, it's wet but dry

Tags: riddle

I have been trying to solve this for a while now and haven't gotten anywhere

> What is light but still dark, it's wet but dry. It has a name but it cannot be spoken. It ends in H

What is the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Can you tell us where you got this riddle from?

Comment: I got it from a friend who told me i would get a reward for solving it. Other than that it does not have any actual context

Comment: Could you ask your friend where they got it from?

Comment: Told me he came up with it himself.

Comment: Because you don't know the answer, I'm not gonna be shy about asking for hints. Are you and your friend fans of wine?

Comment: @Aww_Geez Good point.

Comment: Personally im not, but he might be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [YHWH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton)

What is light but still dark

> "I am the LORD and there is no other.
>  I form the light and create darkness,"
>  - Isaiah 45:6c-7

it's wet but dry

> "When Gideon arose the next morning, he squeezed the fleece and wrung out the dew—a bowlful of water.
>  Then Gideon said to God, 'Do not be angry with me; let me speak one more time.
>  Please allow me one more test with the fleece.
>  This time let it be dry, and the ground covered with dew.'
>  And that night God did so. Only the fleece was dry, and dew covered the ground"
>  - Judges 6:38-40

More generally

> The national God of ancient Israel was seen as the creator of the cosmos. There is some evidence of symbolic linking between the Tetragrammaton and the four classical elements (fire, air, water, earth) where this divine being is thought to embody each of them and their opposites.

It has a name but it cannot be spoken

> Observant Jews and those who follow Talmudic Jewish traditions do not pronounce יהוה‎ nor do they read aloud proposed transcription forms such as Yahweh or Yehovah; instead they replace it with a different term, whether in addressing or referring to the God of Israel. In fact, according to oral Jewish tradition, "He who pronounces the Name with its own letters has no part in the world to come!" Such is the prohibition of pronouncing the Name as written that it is sometimes called the "Ineffable", "Unutterable", or "Distinctive Name", or "Explicit Name"

It ends in H

> At least when written using the Roman alphabet

Comment: If this is the answer, that would have been very difficult. Good job.

Comment: I need to get confirmation from him to see if its correct. I rarely talk to him so might take a while

Comment: Oh wow that was alot more complex than i thought. Good job